# TDD - Assertion Errors running contract tests in R3

Tags: corda

In the contract tests for Corda (from the Git repo for : IOUIssueTests) , the test for mustIncludeIssueCommand() expects an exception , but it does not throw one.

```
   public void mustIncludeIssueCommand() {
        IOUState iou = new IOUState(Currencies.POUNDS(1), ALICE.getParty(), BOB.getParty());

        ledger(ledgerServices, l -> {
            l.transaction(tx -> {
                tx.output(IOUContract.IOU_CONTRACT_ID, iou);
                tx.command(Arrays.asList(ALICE.getPublicKey(), BOB.getPublicKey()), new Commands.DummyCommand()); // Wrong type.
                return tx.failsWith("Contract verification failed");
            });
            l.transaction(tx -> {
                tx.output(IOUContract.IOU_CONTRACT_ID, iou);
                tx.command(Arrays.asList(ALICE.getPublicKey(), BOB.getPublicKey()), new IOUContract.Commands.Issue()); // Correct type.
                return tx.verifies();
            });
            return null;
        });
    }
```

This fails with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception but didn't get one

    at net.corda.testing.dsl.Verifies$DefaultImpls.failsWith(LedgerDSLInterpreter.kt:66)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TransactionDSLInterpreter$DefaultImpls.failsWith(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TestTransactionDSLInterpreter.failsWith(TestDSL.kt:67)
    at net.corda.testing.dsl.TransactionDSL.failsWith(TransactionDSLInterpreter.kt)
```

I tried running the code in the solutions repo , that seems to fail too. Anything that i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the intents behind the Corda training application was to show that failures are expected, in this case you can see that the unit test expects the transaction to fail: `return tx.failsWith("Contract verification failed");`

Looking earlier in the unit test we can see the reason why the test should fail: `new Commands.DummyCommand()` This is not a valid command and the `IOUContract` should fail the transaction because it does not match the `Issue` command.

Switching to the `IOUContract` class there must be a line which checks the command that is contained within the transaction. The method that does this is `tx.commands.requireSingleCommand`. Make sure you pass the right command to require and you should be able to get past this step of the flow test.

I've avoided giving the complete answer here for educational reasons but you can check the answer in the solutions repository of training.